# ghostscript in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ghostscript, postscript

I am experiencing lots of issues with postscript files since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I cannot visualize them with gv, evince, or other similar programs. I cannot parse them into ImageMagick. Here are some examples of the error messages I get:

```
$ convert test1.ps test1.png
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--  --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:972/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:12/20(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 774
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:972/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:12/20(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 774
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `test1.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

This is the error message I get with gv:

```
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stoppeGPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
d_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:969/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:12/20(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 774
```

The problem is not in the file, I tested it with many files where it used to work with Ubuntu 16.04. I believe that this is in line with the various security measures adopted with ghostscript 9.25 in Ubuntu 18.04, and I suspect that it's the same root cause of other problems recently discussed in this site.

Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Post the output of `cat /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml | grep '"PS"'`

Comment: $ cat /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml | grep '"PS"'
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
Thank you for your interest!

Comment: that's ok, seems really to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [abu_bua](https://askubuntu.com/users/790920/abu-bua) and [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) for their feedback.

The **latest patch** of updates fixed the problem, now ghostscript works as expected.

Comment: This seems to be an answer... the problem went away after a system update. Maybe the problem can be considered not-reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

convert doesn't work in 18.04 for either .ps or .eps files. This is a bug in 18.04. Open the .ps file in GIMP image editor instead. GIMP can convert .ps and .eps files to any of its supported image formats.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. The problem is that gimp also relies on ghostscript to interpret ps files.

Comment: @Deky740 My GIMP works OK in 18.04 and I also tested Inkscape in 18.04 which works at converting .ps files too. I made the .ps file I tested using a graphical programming language called dot, so I know the .ps file that I tested is not corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @karel. I tried again, both GIMP and Inkscape, and in both cases it fails to import the ps file, with the same error.